# How to get values from two tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables in SQL Server 2008 and I want to get the details from those 2 tables using join.

T-1 : **vwHardwareConsolidate**

```
|ID|||Qty|Type|Task_Id|
```

T-2 :

```
|MasterID|Task_Id|Act_Qty|
```

I want to get `id, task_name, sum(qty), task_id` from `T1` and `Masterid, Act_Qty` from `T2`

I have tried this query

```
select  
    ID as MasterID, Task_id, Task_Name as Items, 
    SUM(Qty) as Req_Qty, 0 as Act_Qty
from 
    vwHardwareConsolidate  
where 
    type = 'Reqrd' and ID = '21' 
Group by 
    Task_Name,id,Task_id

union 

(select 
    m.MasterID, m.Task_Id, vw.Task_Name as Items, 0 as Req_Qty, m.Act_Qty 
 from 
    vwHardwareConsolidate vw
 Right join
     (select 
          MasterID, m.Task_Id, 0 as Req_Qty, sum(Act_qty) as Act_Qty 
      from 
          tbl_MaterialDistribution_Detail  m
      where 
          MasterID = '21' 
      group by 
          m.Task_Id, MasterID) as m on m.Task_Id = vw.Task_id)
```

`vwHardwareConsolidate`

```
ID    Site_name Qty      Task_Name      Type

1   CITY    1   A16Port_Switch  Reqrd
1   CITY    1   Digital_Camera  Reqrd
1   CITY    1   Electronic_Pen  Reqrd
```

`tbl_MaterialDistribution_Detail`:

```
MasterID|TaskId|Act_qty 
7   31  1
2   32  1
12  39  3
```

Comment: Sum(qty) please explain how the sum is calculated please provide sample data

Comment: please provide sample in and output table

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT T1.Id, T1.SiteName,T1.TaskName,T.Type,T2.Act_Qty,T2.MasterID,T2.Task_Id,SUM(Qty)AS 
Qty FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.Task_Id=T2=Task_Id GROUP BY T1.Id, T1.SiteName,
T1.TaskName,T.Type,T2.Act_Qty,T2.MasterID,T2.Task_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
select t1.ID, t1.Task_Name,Sum(t1.Qty) as Qty,t1.Task_Id,t2.MasterID,t2.Act_Qty
from vwHardwareConsolidate as t1
left outer join table2 as t2
on t2.Task_ID=t1.Task_ID
Group By  t1.ID, t1.Site_name, t1.Task_Name,t1.Qty,t1.Type,t1.Task_Id,t2.MasterID,t2.Act_Qty
```

May this will help you.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/49b70/2)

Answer (score 0):

something this way,

```
select a.id,a.Task_Name,b.qty,c.Act_Qty from vwHardwareConsolidate a inner join
tbl_MaterialDistribution_Detail c on a.id=c.task_id
inner join 
(slect id,sum(qty)qty from vwHardwareConsolidate group by id)b
on a.id=b.id
```